# Intel Graphic Driver installed but not working on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: drivers, graphics, 15.10, intel-graphics, gpu-driver

I have recently installed Ubuntu 15.10 with windows 7. I have followed information given [here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/11/install-intel-graphics-installer-in-ubuntu-15-10/) to install my intel graphics driver. When checking with

```
lspci | grep VGA
```

this is the output:

```
 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
```

System Details:

[image: System configuration]

Still the Display is undetected in the setting. I have struggled a lot for video driver installation. There are no proprietary drivers available.

How should I get the full-res for my PC? Please help!

Comment: 15.10 is EoL, out of support. Please install a supported release.

Comment: @CelticWarrior I have tried the same thing with 16.04 LTS and 14.04 LTS but the results are all same

Comment: Again, install a supported release (for your own sake) and when you do it, if the problem is the same, then ask a new question. We don't support old releases and this question will be closed.